# Can't connect to TFS 2010 Analysis Services

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

I'm trying to setup reporting in TFS 2010.

I can't connect to the Analysis Services database and I also can't rebuild the Analysis services database.

I've tried to connect via TFS Admin console and SSMS and I'm getting this error in SSMS

### Connect to Server

Cannot connect to xxx.com,1031.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)

---

The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found (System)

and this error in TFS Admin

The SQL Server instance that you specified was not found or cannot be reached. Specify another server or instance.

The sql server analysis services service is running.

I used the following article to identify the correct port for SSAS service and I still cannot connect.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2466860

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It was the port number.

I fixed it by using the above link to identify the port number then connecting using TFS Admin tool.